# Linear independence of $3$ vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ with a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine all real numbers $a$ so that the vectors are linearly independent.

$$
c_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
4\\ 
0\\ 
2\\
6\end{bmatrix}+c_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
2\\ 
0\\
2\end{bmatrix}+
c_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
12\\ 
2\\ 
2\\
a\end{bmatrix}=0\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
4c_{1}+&ac_{2}+&12c_{3}&=0\\ 
&2c_{2}+&2c_{3}&=0\\ 
2c_{1}+&&2c_{3}&=0\\
6c_{1}+&2c_{2}+&ac_{3}&=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$c_{2}=-c_{3}\\
c_{1}=-c_{3}$$

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
-4c_{3}-ac_{3}+12c_{3}=0\\
-6c_{3}-2c_{3}+ac_{3}=0
\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow 
8c_{3}-ac_{3}+(-8c_{3}+ac_{3})=0\Rightarrow 0=0 
$$

Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Note that you are using "$\Rightarrow$": you conclude things from the a linear combination being zero. Of course "$0=0$" is a valid conclusion, it just doesn't help to solve your problem. You really want your steps to be equivalences ("$\Leftrightarrow$") so that the solutions in the end are exactly the solutions of the equation you started with. In particular the last step doe *not* satisfy "$\Leftarrow$"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider the two equations you got to at the end, namely $8c_3 - a c_3 = 0$ and $-8c_3 +ac_3 = 0$. These are of course the same equation $8c_3 - a c_3 = 0$. If $a = 8$ then $c_3$ can be anything, and the set of vectors is not linearly independent, since it has infinitely many solutions for $c_1, c_2, c_3$ (for example $c_1=-1, c_2=-1$ and $c_3=1$). If $a$ is anything other than $8$ you have $c_3=0$ which implies $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0$, and you have linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

Last step.  Both equations give $8c_3=ac_3$.  Thus $a\ne8$.